# Keyboard moving "drop" of a cursor up

Tags: android

I have an edittext. When I clicking on this edittext, keyboard is popuping. But it's also moving a "drop" of cursor up (on the height of keyboard). It's happening only one first time [here an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JfyO.jpg). Maybe problem in       `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"`, but I cant delete it, because it's prevents recreating of edittext in my adapter.

activityMain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/changeRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name_change"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="Very very long country name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days_count_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/input"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="Edit" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:minEms="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="666" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/delimiter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_up"
        android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/delimiter2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_up"
        android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />
</RelativeLayout>
```